# scala: method that return varargs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, variadic-functions

From a scala method, I want to return a variable number a Spark columns, like this:

```
def getColumns() : (Column*) = {...}
```

This idea is then to use it with spark sql:

```
myDf.select(getColumns, "anotherColumns"..)
```

The thing is I have about 30 requests that all have the same select clause, that I want to put in common.

Any idea what to replace with the ...? I tried something like:

```
($"col1", "$col2")
```

but it doesn't compile.

Comment: return an array of columns, append any additional entries you want to it, and then expand it with `:_*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
val df = Seq((1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8)).toDF("a","b","c","d")
```

Typecast String to spark columns using map function and append addition column in an array as required.

```
val lstCols = List("a","b")
df.select(lstCols.map(col) ++ List(col("c"),col("d")): _*).show()   

+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|
|  5|  6|  7|  8|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Instead of you code I use te following to have columns instead of strings : val lstCols = Seq($"a" as "aa", $"b" as "bb")
df.select(lstCols ++ Seq($"c", $"d") : _*).show() . Thans for the tip.